# ASP.NET OleDB permissions error

Tags: asp.net, permissions, oledb

I'm uploading an Excel file and then reading data using oledb connection in asp.net but I'm getting the following error:

The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

```
Dim ocmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", conn)
```

Line 12:             conn.Open()
Line 13:             Dim odr As OleDbDataReader = ocmd.ExecuteReader()

conn.open() line is red highlighted for error.

The excel file is uploaded successfully and present in the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your file upload logic look like?  If you're using a FileStream, make sure you're properly closing the stream before trying to use OleDb... if you don't close the stream, the file will remain locked.

Otherwise, make sure that you don't have the uploaded file currently open in Excel..

Comment: The error comes when I run it on remote server. it is perfect when used at localhost

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue in that case...  As a test, try granting full permissions to everyone to the folder that the file is being uploaded to.  If it works in that case, try narrowing down the permissions to just the account that asp.net runs under on that machine.